Is there an efficient way to write this Newton Interpolation form?
Our professor taught us a very simple system to easily deduce a polynomium in a Newton Interpolation form:

I tried to somewhat replicate this structure in my assignment in LaTeX as I had a strong intuition it was possible, and here's what I got:

Here's the MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 1mm}
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{NiceArray}{c|c|c|c|c}
        x & p(x) & c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\ \hline
        3 & 10 & & & \\
        & & \frac{146-10}{7-3} = 34 & & \\
        7 & 146 & & \frac{24-34}{1-3}= 5 & \\
        & & \frac{2-146}{1-7}=24 & & \frac{5-5}{2-3}=0 \\
        1 & 2 & & \frac{-1-24}{2-7}=5 & \\
        & & \frac{1-2}{2-1} = -1 & & \\
        2 & 1 & & &
        \CodeAfter
            \tikz \draw[thick, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=0.5mm] (2-1) -- (2-2);
            \tikz \draw[thick, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=0.5mm] (4-1) -- (4-2);
            \tikz \draw[thick, shorten >=2mm, shorten <=0.5mm] (6-1) -- (6-2);
            \tikz \draw[thick, shorten >=2mm, shorten <=0.5mm] (8-1) -- (8-2);
            \tikz \draw[thick] (2-2) -- (3-3.north west);
            \tikz \draw[thick, shorten >= 1mm] (4-2.east) -- (3-3.west);
            \tikz \draw[thick, shorten >=2mm] (4-2.east) -- (5-3.west);
            \tikz \draw[thick, shorten >= 2mm] (6-2.east) -- (5-3.west);
            \tikz \draw[thick, shorten >=2mm] (6-2.east) -- (7-3.west);
            \tikz \draw[thick, shorten >= 2mm, shorten <= 1mm] (8-2.east) -- (7-3.west);
            \tikz \draw[thick, shorten >= 1mm, shorten <= 1mm] (3-3.east) -- (4-4.west);
            \tikz \draw[thick, shorten >= 1mm, shorten <= 1mm] (5-3.east) -- (4-4.west);
            \tikz \draw[thick, shorten >= 1mm, shorten <= 1mm] (5-3.east) -- (6-4.west);
            \tikz \draw[thick, shorten >= 1mm, shorten <= 1mm] (7-3.east) -- (6-4.west);
            \tikz \draw[thick, shorten >= 1mm, shorten <= 1mm] (4-4.east) -- (5-5.west);
            \tikz \draw[thick, shorten >= 1mm, shorten <= 1mm] (6-4.east) -- (5-5.west);
    \end{NiceArray}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}

The code replicates my professor's system, but the issue is that the "branches" aren't properly formatted. I need to manually adjust their lengths, resulting in inconsistencies on how the branches look. On top of that, I need to create "gap-rows" to place the results from each column in-between the previous one. Any way to maintain the system I desire and bypass these 2 issues?
Edit:
Upon suggestion from @Qrrbrbirlbel, I decided to try an alternative implementation with the nicematrix-package. It resulted in the following code which outputs about the same result as before:
Edit 2:
I re-organized my question with a complete example solving my task with the usage of the nicematrix package. Still need help to optimize it as specified in my "refined question".

The nicematrix package combines tikzmark and tables and might be a much easier approach. Without it, I would do everything in one Tikz picture and would forgo the tabular/array design. Vertical lines aren't really needed. What's happening in the very last column in your picture? Can you provide the mathematical rules that apply?

Ooh, so the nicematrix-package basically has commands like these pre-typeset? Also, how would you do it all in Tikz without an array? Wouldn't that make things even more difficult as you'd then have to construct the array from scratch in Tikz? The last column was just our professor writing the interpolation form of the calculations from before, showing what the end result would look like written out as a polynomium. He made a small notation error, skipping from c_1 to c_3. Above that, he just provided some examples by inserting some x-values to show that we'll get the correct results.

Update
After some discussions with @Atex, I propose a different answer.  It is based on the library positioning.  It introduces two parameters \b and \c to control the vertical distance between the nodes (and so to be able to modify easily and coherently the nodes' positions).

The same image with vertical lines.  The code below will produce this second image.  (For aesthetic reasons as well as conveyed information, I don't think the vertical lines are useful.)

The code
\documentclass[11pt, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math, calc, positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[evaluate={%
    integer \N; 
    \N = 3;  % \N +1 is the number of points
    \M = \N -1;
    \b = .2;
    \c = 2*\b +1;
    \h = \b +\N*\c +\N +2;  % length of vertical lines
  },
  data/.style={%
    rectangle, rounded corners,
    minimum height=1cm, minimum width=1cm, inner sep=.2ex%
  },
  ddif/.style={%
    rectangle, rounded corners,
    minimum height=1cm, minimum width=2.5cm, inner sep=.2ex%
  },
  node distance=\b and 5ex,
  e/.style={-, thin, shorten <=2pt, shorten >=2pt}]

  \node[data] (x) {$x$};
  \node[data, below={\b} of x] (x0) {$3$};
  \node[data, below={\c} of x0] (x1) {$7$};
  \node[data, below={\c} of x1] (x2) {$1$};
  \node[data, below={\c} of x2] (x3) {$2$};
  
  \node[data, right=of x] (f) {$f(x)$};
  \node[data, below={\b} of f] (f0) {$10$};
  \node[data, below={\c} of f0] (f1) {$146$};
  \node[data, below={\c} of f1] (f2) {$2$};
  \node[data, below={\c} of f2] (f3) {$1$};

  \node[ddif, right=of f] (c1) {$c_1$};
  \node[ddif, below right=of f0] (d1_1) {$\frac{146-10}{7-3} = 34$};
  \node[ddif, below right=of f1] (d1_2) {$\frac{2-146}{1-7}=24$};
  \node[ddif, below right=of f2] (d1_3) {$\frac{1-2}{2-1}=-1$};
  
  \node[ddif, right=of c1] (c2) {$c_2$};
  \node[ddif, below right=of d1_1] (d2_2) {$\frac{24-34}{1-3}= 5$};
  \node[ddif, below right=of d1_2] (d2_3) {$\frac{-1-24}{2-7}=5$};
  
  \node[ddif, right=of c2] (c3) {$c_3$};
  \node[ddif, below right=of d2_2] (d3_3) {$\frac{5-5}{2-3}=0$};

  \begin{scope}[blue!70!black, very thin]
    \draw (x.260) -- (c3.280);  % horisontal line
    \draw ($(x.90)!.5!(f.90)$) -- ++(0, -\h);    
    \draw ($(f.90)!.4!(c1.90)$) -- ++(0, -\h);    
    \draw ($(c1.90)!.5!(c2.90)$) -- ++(0, -\h);    
    \draw ($(c2.90)!.5!(c3.90)$) -- ++(0, -\h);    
   \end{scope}
  
  \foreach \i in {0, ...,\N}{%
    \path (x\i) edge[e] (f\i);
  }
  \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using {int(\i +1)}] in {0,..., \M}{%
    \path (f\i) edge[e] (d1_\j);
    \path (f\j) edge[e] (d1_\j);
  }
  \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using {int(\i +1)}] in {1,..., \M}{%
    \path (d1_\i) edge[e] (d2_\j);
    \path (d1_\j) edge[e] (d2_\j);
  }
  \path (d2_2) edge[e] (d3_3)  (d2_3) edge[e] (d3_3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Initial answer

There are two pic objects: show NI and explanation.  The first displays the Newton algorithm; the second insert the explanation for an entry in the algorithm.  The arguments are more or less self explanatory.  You need to invoke newton interpolation which takes the points and the values as arguments in lists and which performs the computations of all the entries in the algorithm.  There is a constant as a third argument that will tune the space between the columns as a multiplicative factor.
The code
\documentclass[11pt, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}  % includes xcolor package
\usetikzlibrary{math, matrix}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
  newton interpolation/.style args={points=(#1), values=(#2), dx=#3}{%
    every node/.style={outer sep=4pt},
    evaluate={%
      real \cst;
      \cst = #3;
      integer \h, \i, \j, \k, \l, \N;
      \i = 0;
      for \tmp in {#1}{%
        \a{\i} = \tmp;
        \i = \i +1;
      };
      \i = 0;
      for \tmp in {#2}{%
        \f{0,\i} = \tmp;
        \i = \i +1;
      };
      \N = \i -1;
      for \j in {1,..., \N}{%
        for \l in {\j, ..., \N}{%
          \i = \j -1;
          \k = \l -1;
          \h = \l -\j;
          \f{\j,\l} = (\f{\i,\l} -\f{\i,\k})/(\a{\l} -\a{\h});
        };
      };
    }
  },
  pics/show NI/.style={%
    code={%
      \tikzmath{%
        for \j in {0,..., \N}{%
          for \l in {\j, ..., \N}{%
            \tmp = \f{\j,\l};
            {%
              \path (\j*\cst, -\l) node (\j-\l)
              {\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=2]{\tmp}};
            };
          };
        };
        for \j in {0,..., \N}{%
          {%
            \path (-1*\cst, -\j) node {\a{\j}};
          };
        };
        {%
          \path (-1*\cst, 1) node {$x_j$};
          \path (0*\cst, 1) node {$f[x_j]$};
          \draw (-.5*\cst, 1) -- (-.5*\cst, -\N -.5);
          \draw (-1.3*\cst, .5) -- ++({(\N +1.7)*\cst}, 0);  
        };
      }
    }
  },
  pics/explanation/.style args={row=#1, column=#2, y=#3}{%
    code={%
      \tikzmath{%
        integer \h, \i, \j, \k, \l;
        \j = #2;
        \l = #1;
        \i = \j -1;
        \k = \l -1;
        \h = \l -\j;
        if \f{\i,\k}>0 then {%
          if \a{\h}>0 then {%
            {%
              \path (\j*\cst, #3) node
              {$\frac{\f{\i,\l} -\f{\i,\k}}{\a{\l} -\a{\h}}$}
              edge[->] (\j-\l);
            };
          } else {%
            {%
              \path (\j*\cst, #3) node
              {$\frac{\f{\i,\l} -\f{\i,\k}}{\a{\l} -(\a{\h})}$}
              edge[->] (\j-\l);
            };
          };
        } else {%
          if \a{\h}>0 then {%
            {%
              \path (\j*\cst, #3) node
              {$\frac{\f{\i,\l} -(\f{\i,\k})}{\a{\l} -\a{\h}}$}
              edge[->] (\j-\l);
            };
          } else {%
            {%
              \path (\j*\cst, #3) node
              {$\frac{\f{\i,\l} -(\f{\i,\k})}{\a{\l} -(\a{\h})}$}
              edge[->] (\j-\l);
            };
          };          
        };
      }
    }
  }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[newton interpolation={points=(-5, -1, 0, 1),
      values=(-2, 6, 1, 3), dx=1.3}]
    \path (0, 0) pic {show NI};
    \path (0, 0) pic {explanation={row=3, column=2, y=-4.5}};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


I'm not that proficient in LaTeX yet that I'm able to construct table structures and such in tikz from scratch. Thus, even if I understood all of your code, it'd be hard and very time-consuming for me to implement. Before your response, I did manage to make a complete answer for my task using the nicematrix-package as suggested by another user, however, in a somewhat comprehensive manner. The branches connecting from each column to the next don't look consistent, but I can understand the logic. I wanted to ask if I could send it to you? Perhaps you can fix the inconsistencies?

Hi @Atex ! I could try to see if I have any idea.  But, as a general rule, I don't think that the configuration you are looking after with every new "divided difference" written in-between the two previous rows is very useful.  I think, it is a good habit to write the new difference on the row of the value that comes with the plus sign, i.e. the "second".  This way, the coefficients of the interpolation appear on the last row.  In case you add one more point, you just complete one more row...

I see your point. Your structure kind of looks like a lower triangular matrix where the elements of the diagonal make up the coefficients. The thing is that the layout our professor taught us is quite easy for me to read. Thus, if a structure like that can be kept without "excessive rows" and the branches being formatted consistently for each column would be ideal. I'll make a 2nd edit where you can see how I solved for my task. If you could optimize/fix it by just using nicematrix combined with simple tikz usage or even only with nicematrix, it'd be very much appreciated!

I've updated my question now to instead include the MWE of how I solved my task completely and tried to formulate my 2 problems in the question more precisely. Hopefully that clarifies and allows for you or anyone else to help me more precisely:)

I don't know how to deal with your new questions and nicematrix.  So, following your ideas, I wrote a different answer that constructs the nodes by hand and uses positioning only.

That's okay - Your attempted approach already looks way better than mine, and I can even understand your code better even though it's still hardcore tikz ! There are some keywords I don't understand, but I get the general functionality of each section. The hard part is the \path \foreacheven though I know they're for constructing loops which iterate over the length of the table?  The last question I have is how would you add the vertical lines for each column?

Hi @Atex.  Thank you for the compliment; I think the general principle should be "Always use TikZ".  I updated the answer and added the vertical lines.  They ask for the control of the height of the drawn elements (and maybe in some cases you will use 5 or 6 points...). So I introduce a variable to control the height; it depends on the number of points.  I also change the color of the vertical and horizontal line...  You might want to make them lighter.  I avoided another \foreach!

I agree with that as a general principle. It is advantageous to be able to construct whatever you desire from scratch in TikZ, because then you can finetune the individual small details. The problem is that the code gets much more disproportionately complex to execute, and someone like me can't comprehend that. Producing code like your example would probably take me a long time and require a way deeper understanding of TikZ than I currently have. Thus, if there's a package which can alleviate the involvement of TikZ, I'd prefer that currently, even at the expense of some customization
